# Picking 2 cards out of 100. What's the probability there is a specific card in those 2?

Tags: probability

There are 100 different gormiti cards. One of those 100 is Magmion and anohter is Electricon. I pick randomly 2 cards of those 100, without replacement. What's the probability of 1 of those 2 cards i randomly picked, to be Magmion?
What's the probability of picking Magmion and Electricon?

Should i use hypergeometric distribution? Any help?

Comment: Just count.  How many different pairs are there?  How many pairs contain at least one of those 2 cards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one "Magmion" card out of 100. The probability that the first card drawn is "Magmion" is 1/100.  The probability the "Magmion" card is not the first card drawn is 99/100.  Then there is one "Magmion" card out of 99.  Under these conditions the probability the second card drawn is "Magmion" is 1/99.  The probability the first card drawn is NOT "Magmion" but the second card is "Magmion" is (99/100)(1/99)= 1/100 also.  So the probability one of the two cards drawn is "Magmion" is 1/100+ 1/100= 2/100= 1/50.

Again the probability the first card drawn is "Magmion" is 1/100.  Given that, there are 99 cards, one of which is "Electricon".  The probability the second card drawn is "Electricon" is 1/99.  The probability the first card drawn is "Magmion" and the second is "Electricon" is (1/100)(1/99)= 1/9900.

Similarly the probability the first card drawn is "Electricon" and the second is "Magmion" is 1/9900.  The probability that the two cards are "Electricon" and "Magmion", in either order, is 1/9900+ 1/9900= 2/9900= 1/4950.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, you *may* use hypergeometric distribution if you wish.   It is just using combinatorics to count equally probable outcomes in events.

When selecting 2 from 100 cards, the probability for selecting 1 from 1 special card and 1 from 99 other cards is ...

When selecting 2 from 100 cards, the probability for selecting 2 from 2 special cards and 0 from 98 other cards is ...